# Does free probability have anything to say about the eigenvalue correlations of random matrices?

Tags: reference-request, random-matrices, free-probability

Free probability provides a compact route to compute the average eigenvalue density for various families of random matrices in the large $N$ limit. Does it provide any route to eigenvalue correlations, which are generally useful in the same limit?

Answer (score 4):

Eigenvalue correlations on the macroscopic level (fluctuations of linear statistics) are in free probability theory captured by the notion of "second order freeness"; a treatment of this can be found in chapter 5 of the book
[Mingo, Speicher: Free Probability and Random Matrices](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/speicher/publikationen/Mingo-Speicher.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The first reference is a Ph.D. thesis, probably the best entry point to the literature of free probability approaches to eigenvalue/eigenvector correlations; the other references involve particular applications.

- [Free probability approach
  to microscopic statistics of random matrix eigenvalues](http://kups.ub.uni-koeln.de/7662/) (2017)
- [Squared eigenvalue
  condition numbers and eigenvector correlations from the single ring
  theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04923) (2016)
- [Complete diagrammatics of the single ring theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07719) (2017)